# find -print0 -name "* *" (whitespace)

Tags: find, pipe, whitespace

Is there a way to pass all filenames containing whitespace to the pipe, or at least those containing spaces? To that end I attempted:

```
~/Desktop> find . -type f -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  -name "* *" | wc -c
       0
~/Desktop> find . -type f -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0  -name "* *" | wc -c
     247
~/Desktop>
```

As you see, the command without -print0 accurately finds no files containing whitespace in the current directory. But with -print0 added, the -name option apparently is not interpreted as I would expect.

Even better than

```
-name "* *"
```

would be some way to specify any whitespace, not just space. Ideally this could be done in find, rather than resorting to "downstream" processing using a perl regular expression.
Ultimately, I want to pipe the filenames to a script that will replace whitespace by some character I specify.

Answer (score 1):

Order matters. This will print every single name because the `-print` action comes before the `-name` filter:

```
find . -print -name "foo"
```

This will print only those named `foo`, because the action comes after the filter:

```
find . -name "foo" -print
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify filenames containing "pathological" whitespace such as tabs and returns, for instance file created by "touch foo$'\r'bar"

Comment: `-name '*[[:space:]]*'` should catch most